# CS0411: The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Tags: c#

I created a C# app which outputs the user country by IP.

I tried to add the second parameter, but it didn't work.

```cs
internal static JToken GetDataFromIPAddress(string ipAddress)
{
    return dbReader.Find(ipAddress);
}
```

problem is in "Find"

I expect the correct compilation, but I can't resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's the type of `dbReader`?

Comment: and what does the Find method return?

Comment: In its current state, it is impossible to reply to this question given the lack of necessary details. Could you either edit your question according to the previous comments, or just tell us if you have already solved your problem since then?